# Unable to add a keyboard layout on Cinnamon

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'd like to try the Polish Colemak layout. It's built into xkb:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules $ grep -ri 'Polish (Colemak)' *
base.extras.xml:            <description>Polish (Colemak)</description>
evdev.extras.xml:            <description>Polish (Colemak)</description>
```

Unfortunately, when trying to add the layout through the Keyboard app ( Layouts > + > write "colemak") the desired layout is not visible. How can I fix it?

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon

Answer (score 1):

I enabled it on Ubuntu 15.04 with the shell command

```
setxkbmap pl colemak
```

The same command *should* work for you.

Comment: This breaks the internal Cinnamon layout switching mechanism